# Java8 stream reducing list of objects with fluent API

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

Is it possible to reduce a list of objects via fluent API method? For instance, I have a `List` of `com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanExpression` which should be united via `com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanExpression#and` method. I can do this via old and reliable for-each like this, but a bit ugly:

```
BooleanExpression result = predicates.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < predicates.size(); i++) {
   result = result.and(predicates.get(i));
}
```

Any chance to rewrite this via Java 8 stream API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) operation:

```
BooleanExpression result = predicates.stream().reduce(BooleanExpression::and).orElseThrow(AssertionError::new);
```

This code will reduce all of your predicates by `and`-ing each intermediate result.

This returns an [`Optional<BooleanExpression>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) in case the list was empty. Since your current code assumes that there is at least one element (by calling `.get(0);` directly), the snippet above throws an `AssertionError` in that case. You could of course use your own exception.

In the case where you can have an identity, which would be a `BooleanExpression` always return `true` here, you could also use

```
BooleanExpression result = predicates.stream().reduce(identity, BooleanExpression::and);
```

Comment: Though even if you have an identity expression, you can use `.reduce(BooleanExpression::and).orElse(identity);` which doesn’t even bother combining the identity with another `BooleanExpression`.